# Website down due to calling AJAX - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I am calling an AJAX after each 5 seconds to update the some info of current logged-in user into database table in PHP.

But it creates a heavy load on my website, and website down when there are multiple users logged-in on my website.

**Is there any way to improve it?**

OR

**Is there any way to resolve my problem using socket.io, OR any JS library (node.js or angular.js or backbone.js or any else)?**

Here is a code i am using:

**Javascript code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   

   update_data(); 

   function update_data() {
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "$URL",
          data: {update_current_time:1},
          success: function(response){
            setTimeout(update_data, 5000);
          },
          error: function(){
            setTimeout(update_data, 5000);
          }
       });
   }
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['update_current_time']))
{
  $query = "UPDATE users SET user_timer=now() WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['id'];
  $db->execute();
  echo 'success';
  die;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of this update? What are you using this for? There's probably a better, completely different approach to solving whatever you're trying to solve here.

Comment: use a websocket and let the websocket push an update the moment a new user logs in or a session expires

Comment: The best possible option is to use websocket.Take a look at this link  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: It would be easier timing actual page loads they would be more a realistic indicator of user activity on the site. Unless the site heavily uses javascript and ajax call; whereby alternative methods of timing would suffice

Comment: Start by considering that the timeout of a TCP connection is way longer than 5 seconds. If you consider any users which has not checked in within 5 seconds to be "offline", you are already discounting people with a temporary network hickup. You can probably safely extend that timeframe to a minute or more.

Comment: @deceze I am updating the time of each user because i want to see the online and offline users in my website at that time.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets can you send me any guide or help to do it? And what will i do when a user will offline?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ and when a user goes offline your socket connection will terminate, if a user does not reconnect within 5 mins or however long your sessions last, you can mark him as signed off.

Comment: You can try one of the approaches listed here http://serverfault.com/questions/17862/list-who-is-currently-connected-to-an-iis-web-server

Comment: Then your definition of "online" is way too narrow. Phoning in every 5 seconds is complete overkill. I'd primarily rely on a script explicitly triggered onbeforeunload to signal that a user has gone *offline*, and various fallbacks and server-side timeouts to make that work regardless of whether onbeforeunload was triggered, with a fallback heartbeat signal of several minutes interval. I'd also store this all in memory instead of hitting a MySQL database each time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a LOT of user and your architecture is completely undersized, one request per user per 5 seconds shouldn't down your architecture.

First, make sure, using the logs that you don't have more requests than that.
Then, be sure to tune your apache/php/mysql configuration so it doesn't take too much memory and time to answer.

Having a request per user every 5 seconds is something you need to totally expect when you create a website, and if your server doesn't handle that correctly, something is off.

Comment: Actually, i want to see which user is online or offline, so above code is running perfectly. But when a number of users comes online, so an AJAX calls after 5seconds for each users. And Mysql database receives alot of requests, i think it leads my website to down state.

Comment: Maybe you could reduce the delay between requests. A 30 seconds or 1 minute delay to see who's online is generally perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you guide me about sockets to resolve this matter? I want to try different approach to resolve this matter which will be very useful for future use.

Comment: Socket won't help you at all.